# Write code with quotation marks, command substitutions and variables into a file

Tags: bash

I want my bash script to write code into a file:

```
echo "mycode" > script.sh
```

My problem is that my code is pretty big and contains many variables, quotation marks and command substitutions.

I want all the variables and command substitutions to be interpreted, the quotation marks to stay as they are and then written into the file.

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: What stops you from using Vim or nano to write into script.sh?

Comment: @ForceBru The script is running on a jailbroken ios device. I dont have any text editor

Comment: you can go to Cydia and get one. What about iFile from some repo where they host cracked apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with heredocs, but the quoting can get tricky.

Here's an example (called `t.sh`):

```
#! /bin/bash

foo=bar

cat > q.sh <<EOS
echo $foo
echo "$foo"
echo "\$foo"
echo '$foo'
echo '\$foo'
bob=$(echo $0)
alice=\$(echo $0)
EOS
```

The resulting script contains:

```
echo bar
echo "bar"
echo "$foo"
echo 'bar'
echo '$foo'
bob=./t.sh
alice=$(echo ./t.sh)
```

Comment: OP isn't asking for no expansion - that's the problem, at least that's how I interpret: "all the variables and command substitutions to be interpreted".

Comment: This worked for me, as i wanted most of the varaibles and command substitutions interpreted. 2 of them, which i didnt wanted to be interpreted, i escaped. If you wand all of them escaped MiguelFCs method would be more efffective. Thanks for all your help :)

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way will be something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat > test.out << \EOF
Hello $WORLD.
EOF
```

And the output will be:

```
Hello $WORLD.
```

This way, you wouldn't need to escape each '$' character individually.